# Ruby question mark in filename

Tags: ruby, file

I have a little piece of ruby that creates a file containing tsv content with 2 columns, a date, and a random number.

```
   #!/usr/bin/ruby

require 'date'
require 'set'

startDate=Date.new(2014,11,1)
endDate=Date.new(2015,9,1)

dates=File.new("/PATH_TO_FILE/dates_randoms.tsv","w+")

rands=Set.new

while startDate <= endDate do
   random=rand(1000)
   while rands.add?(random).nil? do
     random=rand(1000)
   end
   dates.puts("#{startDate.to_s.gsub("-","")}   #{random}")
   startDate=startDate+1
end
```

Then, from another program, i read this file and create a file out of the random number:

```
  dates_file=File.new(DATES_FILE_PATH,"r")
    dates_file.each_line do |line|
      parts=line.split("\t")
      random=parts.at(1)
      table=File.new("#{TMP_DIR}#{random}.tsv","w")
    end
```

But when i go and check the file i see `645?.tsv` for example.
I initially thought that was the line separator in the tsv file (the one containing the date and the random) but its run in the same unix filesystem, its not a transaction from dos to unix
Some lines from the file:

```
head dates_randoms.tsv
20141101        356
20141102        604
20141103        680
20141104        668
20141105        995
20141106        946
20141107        354
20141108        234
20141109        429
20141110        384
```

Any advice?

Comment: Please share a couple of lines from `/PATH_TO_FILE/dates_randoms.tsv`. BTW, you do not close this file descriptor, so there might be any garbage in it.

Comment: @mudasobwa: it's the newline

Comment: @lurker that was a mistake thx for noticing, the random variable is being picked up within the `puts` command of the first snippet.

Comment: @mudasobwa the `file.close` is called in the next piece of code that is not shown in that snipped as its irrelevant, but thx for noticing

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
 parts = line.split("\t")
 random = parts.at(1)
```

`line` there will contain a trailing newline char. So for a line

```
"whatever\t1234\n"
```

`random` will contain `"1234\n"`. That newline char then becomes a part of filename and you see it as a question mark. The simplest workaround is to do some sanitization:

```
random = parts.at(1).chomp
# alternatively use .strip if you want to remove whitespaces 
# from beginning of the value too
```

Comment: Indeed. It looks like the substitution is being done at filesystem level.